# jQuery Table Plugin with Group By

Tags: jquery, plugins, group-by

I need a jQuery Plugin that makes a Sortable and Groupable List of my Data.
My Data is a Tasklist with a duedate, and i would like to have them grouped by date, and sortable.
Is there a plugin that can handle that?
I'm actually using dataTables, but it has some strange behavoir and bugs...

Like:

```
16-10-2009
- Task 1
- Task 2
17-10-2009
- Task 4
18-10-2090
- Task 3
```

Answer (score 7):

Many jQuery plugins can provide you a smart solution:

Best for simple groups:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Easier:
http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/expandable-rows

My recommendation to complex groupings:
http://www.hanpau.com/index.php?page=jqtreetable

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 3):

The original question said they were using dataTables, which was probably why this answer wasn't offered:

http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html

However, things have probably changed in the last couple of years, so it's quite likely that dataTables is the best answer today.

Answer (score 2):

http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/tablegroup/

Answer (score 2):

Check out ShieldUI's Grid grouping functionality:

http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-grouping/grouping

It is a very flexible grid with a lot of customization options available.

Answer (score 1):

For table sorting, you can check out **[**tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)****

Comment: I can't group there
The grouping is imporant!