# jQuery: count array elements by value

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array of elements assembled by:

```
timeArray = [];
$('.time_select').each(function(i, selected) {
  timeArray[i] = $(selected).val();
});
```

where `.time_select` is a class on a group of different HTML select tags.

What I'd like to do is count the number of times a specific value occurs in `timeArray`. Strangely enough, I haven't found any concise solution... surely there's a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
timeArray = [];
occurs = {};
$('.time_select').each(function(i, selected) {
  timeArray[i] = $(selected).val();
  if (occurs[timeArray[i]] != null ) { occurs[timeArray[i]]++; }
  else {occurs[timeArray[i]] = 1; }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

You should try abstracting that into a function using the (under-used) `$.each()` function, I'd say.

```
function countElement(item,array) {
    var count = 0;
    $.each(array, function(i,v) { if (v === item) count++; });
    return count;
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
var a = ['foo','bar','foo'];
var b = countElement('foo',a); // should return 2
```

Answer (score 2):

JS doesn't have many built-in functions for dealing with arrays. This is about as concise as it gets:

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
    count += (timeArray[i] == targetValue);
}
```

If you're willing to incur the overhead of an additional library, then [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) supplies a number of handy utility functions. Using underscore.js, the above code can be simplified to:

```
_(timeArray).reduce(function(m, num) {return m + (num == targetValue);}, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the underscore.js method. I was wondering if there was something shorter than `reduce` suppose not. Btw, check out [lodash.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore) a higher-performance, either compatible (or more consistent drop-in).

Answer (score 0):

You need grouping.  See [jQuery Table Plugin with Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576908/jquery-table-plugin-with-group-by)