# How to count the number of occurrences of each item in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array as follows,

```
var arr = ['ab','pq','mn','ab','mn','ab']
```

Expected result

```
arr['ab'] = 3
arr['pq'] = 1
arr['mn'] = 2
```

Tried as follows,

```
$.each(arr, function (index, value) {
    if (value) 
        arr[value] = (resultSummary[value]) ? arr[value] + 1 : 1;
});

console.log(arr.join(','));
```

Comment: There is no such thing like a "jQuery array".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615916/jquery-count-array-elements-by-value

Answer (score 58, accepted):

no need to use jQuery for this task — this example will build an object with the amount of occurencies of every different element in the array in `O(n)`

```
var occurrences = { };
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
   occurrences[arr[i]] = (occurrences[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log(occurrences);        // {ab: 3, pq: 1, mn: 2}
console.log(occurrences['mn']);  // 2
```

> [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Gt6V/)

---

You could also use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to obtain the same result and avoid a `for-loop`

```
var occurrences = arr.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  obj[item] = (obj[item] || 0) + 1;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(occurrences);        // {ab: 3, pq: 1, mn: 2}
console.log(occurrences['mn']);  // 2
```

> [Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gckta8vu/)

Comment: +1 for adding a fiddle to demonstrate your answer. Why the downvotes?

Comment: You can also use a nice shorthand, such as `obj[arr[i]] = (obj[arr[i]] || 0) + 1`. Your solution works as long as you don't care about data types, but if you want to distinguish between `"2"` and `2`, you have to encode that information too (just saying).

Comment: good point for the shorthand :)

Comment: Can someone explain how this works?

Comment: not sure how this works still. i thought reduce is a sum , but this reduce initialize as a empty object, where is the check to see if the array items match

Comment: I would appreciate if someone would explain - code by code - on how exactly the "reduce" function can accomplish this.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is the simplest way how to count occurrences with same value in array.

```
var a = [true, false, false, false];
a.filter(function(value){
    return value === false;
}).length
```

Comment: In one line : a.filter((value) => value === false).length

Answer (score 6):

if you don't want a solution that requires a library, and don't have to support legacy javascript:

```
var report = {};

arr.forEach(function(el){
  report[el] = report[el] + 1 || 1;
});
```

Or if you want to do it using jQuery:

```
var report = {};

$.each(arr,function(i,el){
  report[el] = report[el] + 1 || 1;
});
```

This uses [short-circuit logic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Control_structures) to test for conditions and set values. I think it's a pretty concise and readable way to do javascript.

```
console.log( report );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [$.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

**Example:**

```
var arr = ['ab','pq','mn','ab','mn','ab']

jQuery.grep(arr, function(a){
   return a == 'ab'
}).length // 3
```

**if supporting ie8 is not necessary.**

```
['ab','pq','mn','ab','mn','ab'].filter(function(value){
    return value == 'ab'
}).length // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = {};
function count(input){
  var tmp = 0;
  if(result.hasOwnProperty(input)){
     tmp = result[input];
     result[input]=tmp+1;
  }else{
    result[input]=1;
  }
}
```

above function will help you to count the num of the same string in an Array.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [Sugar](http://sugarjs.com/) library it's just:

```
arr.count('ab');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nF6P7/20/)**

See: [Array count API](http://sugarjs.com/api/Array/count).

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you are trying to do?

```
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    if (!resultSummary[value]){
        resultSummary[value] = 0;
    }
    resultSummary[value] += 1;
});
```

this code will count the occurrences of each string in the array and store the results in `resultsArray`

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['ab','pq','mn','ab','mn','ab']



function getCount(arr,val)
{
    var ob={};
    var len=arr.length;
    for(var k=0;k<len;k++)
    {
        if(ob.hasOwnProperty(arr[k]))
        {
            ob[arr[k]]++;
            continue;
        }
        ob[arr[k]]=1;
    }
    return ob[val];
}



//run test
alert(getCount(arr,'ab'));//3
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/dmx4y/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['ab','pq','mn','ab','mn','ab'];
var result = { };
   for(i=0;i<arr.length;++i) 
   {
       if(!result[arr[i]])
           result[arr[i]]=0;
       ++result[arr[i]];
   }

for (var i in result){
console.log(i+":"+result[i]);
}
```