# Get Unique Key-Value count as an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've got the following response from the server:

[image]

I want to get the unique key with the occurrence count.
In the following format:

```
0:{"name":"physics 1","count":2}
1:{"name":"chem 1","count":6}
```

I've already checked [How to count the number of occurrences of each item in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649255/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-each-item-in-an-array) but that is not I want.

Comment: have you tried map for the same?

Comment: @DeepakJha, can you show me how to do that?

Comment: ok give me a moment let me write one for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an es6 solution.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'physics 1',
    questionId: 1,
    questionNr: 1
}, {
    name: 'physics 1',
}, {
    name: 'chem 1',
}, {
    name: 'chem 1',
}, {
    name: 'chem 2',
}];

const grouped = data.reduce((groups, cur) => {
    const key = cur.name;

    groups[key] = (groups[key] || 0) + 1;

    return groups;
}, {});

const result = Object.keys(grouped).map(key => ({name: key, count: grouped[key]}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
var source = [
    {'section_name': 'test1'},
    {'section_name': 'test2'},
    {'section_name': 'test1'},
];

var temp = {};
for (var i = source.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var key = source[i].section_name;
    if (!temp[key]) {
        temp[key] = 0;
    } 

    temp[key] += 1;
}

var keys = Object.keys(temp);
var result = [];
for (var i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var key = keys[i];

    result.push({"name":key,"count":temp[key]});
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function this uses map and filter

```
 t.reduce((f,l)=>{
    var k=f.filter(elem=>elem.section_name==l.section_name);
    if(k.length==1) k[0].count++;
    else f.push({section_name:l.section_name,count:1})
    return f;
},[] )
```

you can check this against this to verify

```
var t=[{section_name:"Physics"},{section_name:"Physics"},{section_name:"Chemistry"},{section_name:"Chemistry"},{section_name:"Physics"}]
```